# How to total up a column of a database and display it through a label in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I would like to calculate the total of a db column (Amount) and display it on a label next to the total label in the view. I am unsure how to do carry out this particular task, should it be done in Javascript? or what other methods can I use? 
This is my project...

**MODEL**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace webassignment.Models
    {
        public class Donation
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName{ get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public decimal Amount { get; set; }
            public decimal TaxBonus { get; set; }
            public string Comment { get; set; }

        }
        public class DonationDBContext: DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Donation> Donation { get; set; }

        }
  }
```

**INDEX**

```
  // GET: Donations
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Donation.ToList());
    }
```

**INDEX VIEW**

```
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DisplayName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaxBonus)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DisplayName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaxBonus)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}




</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in View, but better way would be to create a ViewModel, i am giving you basic idea how you can do it in View for time being :

```
@{

   int totalAmount;
   if(Model !=null)
   {
      totalAmount = Model.Sum(x=>x.Amount);
   } 
}
```

and down display it in html where ever you want:

```
<h1>@totalAmount</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are passing to the razor view a List of Donations so you should be able to use the extension methods for collections like model.Sum(x=> x.Amount) within your display.